# How do I move all the data files from many folders to its sub-folders through Python coding?

Tags: python-2.7

I imported `os` and `shutil` modules to accomplish this task. But it is giving the following error message when I use `os.path.join root_dir with fi_name` to store source file:

> can't concatenate str with list type

How do I accomplish this task?

Comment: As the error message says your file name is a list; probably a list of file names.

Comment: yes.. correct. I have many number of folders which i store in a list which i manipulate from "for" loop and many files which i process it again from "for" loop as this also accessing from a list.

Answer (score 0):

This code will move all files in the current directory and sub-directories of current directory to a new sub-directory called `sub_folder.

```
import os


new_folder_name = 'sub_folder'
base_path = os.getcwd()

new_folder_add = os.path.join(base_path, new_folder_name)
if not os.path.isdir(new_folder_add):
    os.mkdir(new_folder_name)

walk = os.walk(base_path)
for level in walk:
    if level[0] == new_folder_add:
        continue
    for fname in level[2]:
        file_add = os.path.join(level[0], fname)
        new_file_add = os.path.join(new_folder_add, fname)
        # this will replace if there exists an other file with new_file_add address
        os.rename(file_add, new_file_add)
```

Comment: Thanks Farbod Shahinfar:  I will tell you clearly my problem. For example, I have two folders called "Ford" and "Hyundai".  Each folder "Ford" and "Hyundai" is having sub-folder called "Archive" to store old data files.  I want to move all the files to its "Archive" folders respectively.  My code was like: